# Which Azure monitoring service to use for visualizing relationship between components?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring

We are designing a monitoring solution for an `Azure App Service web app` application that is using the Application Insights SDK and Azure Blob storage and an Azure SQL Database instance. How do we visualize relationship between components? Figure 2 in [this official post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-activity-logs) from Azure team show some of the things you can do with Activity log. But I'm not sure if we can visualize components using Azure Activity log?

**UPDATE**

To be more specific: Since our case is related to a Web Application, by `visualizing components` we mean `visualizing application components`

Comment: For visualize relationship between components, do you mean it may have an effect like [App Insights Application map](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-app-map#composite-application-map)?

Comment: @IvanYang Do you happen to know if `Application Map` different than `Service Map` in Azure?

Comment: @nam, you can think of Application Map as a visualization for application components. Service Map is used to visualize how VM/VMSS interact with each other and outside world.

Answer (score 2):

The right answer is the Application Map that is a part of Application Insights.

So, your answer on the exam should be Azure Application Insights :)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Monitor does not provide any resource visualization services.  Instead, it is the service whereby you can gain access to logs, metrics, and alerting capabilities for your Azure resources.

If you are wanting to visualize your resources and relationships to one another, then take a look at http://armviz.io.  This will visualize your resources in a resource group and draw relationship lines between resources (when applicable).

Comment: Azure Monitor provides a way to visualize different components using Application Map and Service Map.